# Filtering Data from a specific column

Tags: ms-access, vba, filtering

Hello Everyone I am at a dilemma I am trying to find out a way to filter out certain data in a column field I have an idea on how to do this but I do not know the correct syntax to use. First here is the table and here is the code structure I would like to write.

```
for i=1 to length of column First Match
    for j=1 to length of column Second Match

    If ((value of the data in column First Match = 15) OR (value of the data in column FirstMatch = 1)) AND
       ((value of the data in column Second Match = 15) OR (value of the data in column Second Match = 1)) 
    Then
        Filter the data and append so the filtered datas are saved for both First Match and Second Match
    end if
    next
next
```

I am trying to filter out the data that is a 15 and 1 so that only data that have the values 0,2,3,4,5,6...14 will be shown for instance the information of john and steve will not be shown because both the first and second match fields have a 1 or 15 but the rest of data will be shown my form is a split form setup.

Is my method correct?

---

```
First Name    Last Name    First Match    Second Match
James         Matheson         0               2
Monroe        Labonson         4               3
Barack        Obama            2               5
Frederick     Douglas          3               4
Steve         MCGowan          1               1
John          Seals            15              15
Mike          Omalley          14              15



Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")

Do While Not rs.EOF
If rs!Fields("First Match") > 1 And rs!Fields("First Match") < 15 And rs!Fields("Second Match") > 1 And rs!Fields("Second Match") < 15 Then

End If
Loop
```

Comment: I need more information about the order of the `OR`s and `AND`s in your logic.  Parentheses are your friend.

Comment: Is the problem more clear now?

Comment: Yes.  I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution apparently it was just a misunderstanding because the first time I tried this code I thought it was wrong but it was because my field names did not have spaces in between the first time I wrote them.

```
Me.Filter = ""
Me.Filter = "[First Nam]<>'Jamie' AND [Last Nam]<>'Cartman'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 0):

With a better understanding (I hope) I've reproduced your data in Access and built a query that does what you seem to ask.  The best way to see this is to create a new query, not add a table, and go directly to SQL view.  Paste the following SQL statement (the one in quotes) in and replace `matchFilter` with your table name.

In your event code you can create a recordset based on the SQL:

```
Dim sSQL as string, rs as Recordset

sSQL = "SELECT matchFilter.[First Name], matchFilter.[Last Name], matchFilter.[First Match], matchFilter.[Second Match] " & _
"FROM matchFilter " & _
"WHERE ((([First Match]<>1 And [First Match]<>15 And [Second Match]<>1 And [Second Match]<>15)=True))"
 Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
 ' now do what you want
```

#### Wrong answer below!

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("yourTableName")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Fields("col1") > 1 AND rs!Fields("col1") < 15 AND rs!Fields("col2") > 1 AND rs!Fields("col2") Then
        'do what you have to do with filtered out records
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Can you explain the line of code with rs and the col1 and col2 is it the actualy field names or the column number you are specifying.

Comment: Correct.  `rs` is the recordset (probably your table) and `col1` and `col2` are the field names you're testing. I assumed (correctly?) that you wanted to include only those values >=2 and <=15 and that there was no correlation between values in col1 and col2.

Comment: I tried to run it without adding any filter in it says "object required" at the line where Do while is

Comment: I've expanded my answer.  You'll want to spend some time looking at Developer help in Access to learn more about using VBA. The `object required` message was because the `rs` variable was not initialized (the `Dim...` statement) and unassigned (the `Set...` statement)

Comment: I have tried the code again but this time it cannot find the fields within my table which does not make sense.

Comment: Post your code and I'll see what we can do with it when I get back.  Add your table structure, too, if you can.

Comment: I have added both the modified code and table in my original post.

Comment: Just to recap I am trying to filter out data that has the first match and second match as 1 or 15. So in this case Steve and John's information will not show in the table after it is filtered.

Comment: How can I run the code that is in SQL view? There is no event tied to it.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to go with this?  The above will create a query you can use as a recordset in VBA. The recordset can be used in an event.  I'll add a snippet that shows how, but I otherwise need more info.

Comment: geoB please refer to this post on the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696371/how-to-bind-a-form-to-an-sql-statement-in-microsoft-access