# How to bind a form to an SQL statement in microsoft access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, binding, filtering

**Edit

Hello Everyone I am tryng to include an SQL statement in to my vba so that I can easily sort through data and filter. So I have found way to include SQL in to my VBA but I get an error that says "The RunSQL action requires a SQL statement" but clearly the SQL statement is within the strSQL variable.

```
Private Sub buttonNot_Click()


Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT Table1.[FirstNam], Table1.[LastNam]" & _
"FROM Table1 " & _
"WHERE ((([FirstNam]) <> 'Jamie') AND (([LastNam]) <> 'Cartman'));"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

Me.Filter = ""
Me.Filter = "FirstNam<>'Jamie' AND LastNam<>'Cartman'"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can someone take a look at the code and tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click on `buttonNot`?

Comment: it is suppose to run the sql statment and then Me.Filter is suppose to filter the data so the sql statement essentially goes through all the data in the two columns and then Me.Filter = "FirstNam<>'Jamie' AND Lastnam<>'Cartman'" will filter data that is not equal to jamie or cartman

Answer (score 0):

me.recordsource = {SQL string}

Make sure you turn the filter on after appending the query string.

Comment: I modified my post I think I found a way to include SQL statement but having errors if you can take a look at it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a SELECT query from the DoCmd.RunSQL query, that can only be used for Action or Data Definition queries (INSERT INTO, UPDATE, CREATE, etc.).

[Microsoft Dev Center Docs on DoCmd.RunSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (I know, I included a link, shame on me) :o

I really like @ClassyBear 's answer.  That line of code is equivalent to going to the Property Sheet of the Form in design view and under Data, changing the Record Source Property.  There you can either choose a table/query or click on the ... and create one in the query designer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub buttonNot_Click()


Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT Table1.[FirstNam], Table1.[LastNam]" & _
"FROM Table1 " & _
"WHERE ((([FirstNam]) <> 'Jamie') AND (([LastNam]) <> 'Cartman'));"


Me.RecordSource = strSQL

'DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

'Me.Filter = ""
'Me.Filter = "FirstNam<>'Jamie' AND LastNam<>'Cartman'"

End Sub
```